# How to change the default values of zencart database

Tags: database, zen-cart, zen

How do I replace the default values of zencart that is stored during the installation of zencart?

Comment: Please explain in detail which value you want to change and why?

Comment: Actually I have created a template for Zencart and have edited the pages a lot. It does not work if i replace the default values of Zencart with that of mine. One way I found is that to empty up all the tables after zencart installation and then import my database. But I just want to know that is there any other way to do that? Like during the Zencart installation.

Comment: i thinks this links help you http://www.zen-cart.com/showthread.php?75339-How-to-make-template and http://www.zen-cart.com/content.php?180-how-do-i-create-a-new-custom-template

Answer (score 0):

Most default values for Zen Cart configuration can in fact be changed using the built in Admin panel.  If you're having trouble tracking down a particular value, take a look at the Search Configuration Keys contribution:

http://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=1107

which shows you how to get to a particular value through the admin interface.

Perhaps you'd like to specify which values you'd like to change and we can help you further.